# How to import module at same directory level?

Tags: python

My project is set up as follows:

```
/python-tools
  - __init__.py
  - /module_a
    - __init__.py
    - module_a.py
  - /module_b
    - __init__.py
    - module_b.py
  - /common
    - __init__.py
    - common.py
```

I'm trying to import `common.common` into `module_a.py` and `module_b.py` like this:

```
from common.common import CommonClass
```

But I'm receiving `ModuleNotFound` errors.  I've read through the documentation, and as far as I know it should be set up correctly in packages so that these modules could be imported into one another.

Many of the answers online recommend modifying the `sys.path` to do imports, but that seems absurd to me.  I used to work in Python quite a bit and I remember being able to import modules without that hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use leading dots (`..`) on your imports to move upward in the directory structure.

Here is an example of my structure:

```
import_test/
├── aspen/
│   └── aspen.py
├── birch/
│   ├── birch.py
│   └── birch_leaf.py
└── common/
    └── common.py
```

And here are the content of the files, notice that using two leading dots moves up one directory level to within `import_test`, from there you can access the underlying modules.  Also notice you don't need the `__init__.py` files.

##### `aspen.py`

```
from ..common.common import CommonClass

class AspenClass(CommonClass):
    def root(self):
        print('pain in my aspen!')
```

Here in the `birch` directory, we can import from a sibling file using just one dot in the import statement, as in `birch_leaf.py` below

##### `birch.py`

```
from ..common.common import CommonClass

class BirchClass(CommonClass):
    def root(self):
        print('birch, please!')
```

##### `birch_leaf.py`

```
from .birch import BirchClass

class BirchLeafClass(BirchClass):
    def fall(self):
        print('i am falling!')
```

##### `common.py`

```
class CommonClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = None
```

This set of modules imports and runs using:

```
from import_test.aspen import aspen
from import_test.birch import birch_leaf

aspen.AspenClass()
birch_leaf.BirchLeafClass()
```